# Parentheses matching program using stacks (not STL template stacks)

Tags: c++, reference, static, stack, member

I am making a parentheses matching program for my homework and I am not quite sure how to go about this exactly. I am getting errors when calling my stack functions saying a nonstatic member reference must be made using a relative a specific object in  the is_balanced function. Why is this error occurring and how can I fix it? Thanks for the help.

```
    #include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include "StringStack.h"


using namespace std;

char parentest[];

int main() {

    //variables

    string paren;

    StringStack *stack;

    //user input

    cout << "Please enter a string of parentheses";

    cin >> paren;

    //turn string into char array

    char parentest[paren.length] = paren;

    //set size of the stack equal to the length of the char array.

    stack->stackSize = parentest.length;

    //display the string of balanced parantheses

    cout << is_balanced(parentest);

    system("Pause");

    return 0;

}

//balances the parentheses and returns the string

bool is_balanced(string s) {
    bool status;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length, i++) {

        cout << s[i] << endl;

    StringStack::push(s[i]);
    }
    StringStack::isEmpty();
    if (StringStack::isEmpty) {
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}

//constructor creates an empty stack

StringStack::StringStack(int size)

{

    stackArray = new string[size];

    stackSize = size;

    top = -1;

}

//copy constructor

StringStack::StringStack(const StringStack &obj) {

    //creates stack array

    if (obj.stackSize > 0) {

        stackArray = new string[obj.stackSize];

    }

    else {

        stackArray = nullptr;

    }

    //copies stack contents

    stackSize = obj.stackSize;

    for (int count = 0; count < stackSize; count++) {

        stackArray[count] = obj.stackArray[count];

    }

    //set top of stack

    top = obj.top;

}



//Destructor

StringStack::~StringStack() {

    delete[] stackArray;

}

//puts a value at top of the stack

void StringStack::push(string p) {

    if (isFull()) {

        cout << "The stack is full. \n";

    }

    else {

        top++;

        stackArray[top] = p;

    }



}

void StringStack::pop() {

    if (isEmpty()) {

        cout << "the stack is empty";

    }

    else {

        top--;

        return top;

    }



}

bool StringStack::isFull() const {



    bool status;



    if (top == stackSize - 1) {

        status = true;

    }

    else {

        status = false;

    }

    return status;

}

bool StringStack::isEmpty() const {

    bool status;



    if (top == -1) {

        status = true;

    }

    else {

        status = false;

    }

    return status;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're calling non-static member functions as though they were static. You also never allocate an instance of StringStack, though you have a StringStack pointer. When you dereference that pointer at `stack->stackSize = parentest.length;` you're going to have a segmentation fault.
This `char parentest[paren.length] = paren;` is also wrong.

There is almost nothing correct about the code you've shown.

This is an example of how you need to instantiate your class and how to invoke member functions:

```
StringStack stack(100);
string s( "a string" );
stack.push( s );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand what I'm doing wrong now.